# Crystal Reports Some Data not Showing

Tags: crystal-reports

I have a Crystal Report that missing data in an odd way. Three items are missing data. The data does exist in the dataset when I run the query directly on SQL Server but I can't get them to show on the report.

[image]
[image]

Here's my SQL code:

```
 SELECT "PO_PurchaseOrderDetail"."PurchaseOrderNo", "PO_PurchaseOrderDetail"."ItemCode", 
"PO_PurchaseOrderDetail"."QuantityOrdered", "PO_PurchaseOrderDetail"."QuantityReceived", 
"CI_Item"."UDF_COMMODITY_CODE", "PO_PurchaseOrderDetail"."CommentText", 
"PO_PurchaseOrderDetail"."ItemCodeDesc"
 FROM   "dbo"."PO_PurchaseOrderDetail" "PO_PurchaseOrderDetail" 
 LEFT OUTER JOIN "dbo"."CI_Item" "CI_Item" ON 
"PO_PurchaseOrderDetail"."ItemCode"="CI_Item"."ItemCode"
 WHERE  "PO_PurchaseOrderDetail"."PurchaseOrderNo"='0129281'
```

Does anyone know how I would correct this? Thanks for your help!

Comment: Still not sure what Crystal was doing but I fixed the problem. I converted the above query to a view. That fixed it.